# clock() vs clock_gettime() resolution difference

Tags: c, linux, time, clock

Update: Operator error.. :( 2nd loop was 1/10th of the first one. Typo. With that corrected numbers are much closer.

In the code snippet below I am measuring the time it takes for a loop using clock() and clock_gettime(). Its a 64 bit Ubunutu. CLOCK_PER_SEC value is 1000000.

```
int main() {
struct timespec ts, te;
clock_t s, e;
int i, temp = 0;;
s = clock();
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    temp += i;
}
e = clock();
printf("%.6f\n", 1.0 * (e-s)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &ts);
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    temp += i;
}
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &te);

printf("%lu %lu\n", (long)(te.tv_sec - ts.tv_sec),
                    (long)(te.tv_nsec - ts.tv_nsec));
```

}

one sample output.. (in multiple runs I see them to be in the same range)

0.000068
0 4449

In the measurement using clock_gettime() the loop took ~4000 nanoseconds (~4 microseconds). But the measurement with clock() gives 68 microseconds.

Why is clock() off by such a big margin ?

Comment: Why are the two `i` loops not the same length? One is 10 times the other? And both are quite short operations anyway. Give it some real meat to work on, to far exceed the granularity of the clocks, and make sure the compiler doesn't optimize the unused results away.

Comment: argh.. my bad.. I was trying with different numbers in the loop and had this typo. With that corrected, numbers are in much closer. The difference is probably because of the approximation clock() does. I don't have any portability concerns right now. So will use clock_gettime(). Thanks.

Comment: And remember that just because `struct timespec` has `tv_nsec` field in nanoseconds, that doesn't imply its significance. You can test such things in a tight loop checking / reporting when that field changes, and by how much it changes, to establish the granularity.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that in a Linux VM the highest resolution I could get was 10 microseconds with clock_gettime() where as in a physical host the resolution is much higher..